# Preventing a dialog from showing multiple times

Tags: c#, xna

I have the following piece of code:

```
        else if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.H))
        {
            Help help = new Help();
            help.ShowDialog();
        }
```

For some reason, if I hold the H key, the dialog opens multiple times:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the Help dialog as a member of your class. Initialize it once, and change your code for this:

```
    else if (state.IsKeyDown(Keys.H))
    {
        if (!help.Visible)
             help.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `XNA` for your input, then save the previous `KeyState` and then do a check to see if the previous `KeyState` is released and the current `KeyState` is pressed.

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203902%28v=XNAGameStudio.40%29.aspx) will help you correctly resolve the problem.

Comment: While checking to see if the dialog is already open will work, I think this answer is more correct. Basically what's happening when you press your H key is that the Game loop executes, very, very quickly and the Update method is called around 60 times per second, this means that even if you held the H key down for 1/10 of a second, your dialog would open 6 times (because the code in your Update() method would fire 6 times.) To correctly fix the issue, you have to keep a class level variable storing the previous keyboard state.

Comment: But launching a new instance of the dialog every time the key is pressed is a clear design flaw.

Comment: @r2d2rigo: Yes, it is a design flaw.  With your suggestion and this answer, I believe we have the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use the [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) Event, and you could use the [KeyUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx) Event (or the [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx)).

Another workaround would be to use a [singleton pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) on your Help Popup.